# What is the default timeout for Azure WebJobs SDK jobs?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobssdk

I'm using the Azure WebJobs SDK (v 2.0). What is the default execution timeout for a method decorated with QueueTrigger, for example.  This is running on a web app on a Standard (S1) App Service Plan.

```
public class Functions
{
    public static void HandleMessage(
        [QueueTrigger("my-queue")] string message,
        TextWriter log
    )
    {
        // Long running process
        ...
```

Assuming this method would take a very long time to complete naturally, how long would this run until Azure gives up and terminates execution?

Comment: By execution timeout, do you mean "how long can a method triggered by a message run until Azure gives up and terminates execution", the QueueTrigger's polling interval, or "how long will the WebJob continue to listen to a queue with no activity before the job is unloaded if Always On isn't specified?"

Comment: @RobReagan - Edited the question to clarify.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is my understanding that a WebJob function will run indefinitely or until one of the following occurs:

- If you've marked a WebJob method with the [TimeoutAttribute](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs/TimeoutAttribute.cs), and the specified timeout period has elapsed. A FunctionTimeoutException will then be thrown.
- The method throws an exception which will halt execution.
- You don't pay your Azure bill, and Microsoft suspends your account.
- The universe dies a heat death.

I can't find any mention of a default function execution time limit, and I've had some methods that have run for quite a long time. The WebJobs SDK is open source, and you can view the code [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk).

Comment: Also if you add a message which is identical to one already running it will stop the one that is running with message "New queue message detected"

Comment: If the underlying VM that's hosting the process goes down, then the WebJob will stop too. This is why resiliency is important too.